# Can I use a mixed effects model to analyze data that is tightly spatially aggregated?

Tags: mixed-model, poisson-distribution

I would like to know if it is valid to use a mixed effects model to analyze nested data where the lowest units of the hierarchy were *not* sampled randomly but are adjacent to each other spatially in a grid.  Biologically, spatially adjacent sampling units can experience different conditions, but they might also be very similar.

**Details of the experiment:**
I am analyzing data from a forestry experiment where we counted the number of tree seedlings in 12 m x 12 m plots.  We have 10 plots, five that were fenced to exclude herbivores and five that were unfenced controls.  For survey purposes each plot is divided into 36 subplots that are 2 m x 2m.  The number of seedlings per subplot varies from 0 to >150,  is poisson distributed and probably zero inflated.  The plots in which the subplots are nested can therefore vary in two respects:  the total number of seedlings summed across all subplots, and the number of subplots that have at least one seedling in them.

A single plot looks something like this, where each letter represents a 2 x 2 subplot:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f
g  h  i  j  k  l
m  n  o  p  q  r
s  t  u  v  w  x
y  z  &  @  #  A
B  C  D  E  F  G
```

**Questions:**
**1)**Is it valid to analyze this data at the subplot level and use plot as a random effect, or does the spatial aggregation of the data require me to analyze it at the plot level?
**2)**Could I represent the spatial aggregation of the subplots by adding another level to the hierarchy by grouping adjacent subplots together with another random effect (eg, grouping the above subplots a, b, c, g, h, i, and m, n, o together).